# Inlines move downwards when height of containing TextBlock gets too small

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this very small code snippet:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5">
    <TextBlock FontSize="100">
        Hel<Border Width="20" Height="75" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5"/>lo!
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

And I notice that there is a certain height threshold where the inline Border starts moving downwards:

[image: illustrating the bug]

Is there a way to avoid this? I know I can change `BaselineAlignment` on the `InlineUIContainer` but I would like to keep the object aligned with the text, and changing it to anything else than `BaselineAlignment.Baseline` breaks the alignment.

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should report it to MS.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a Rectangle, instead of a border?

Comment: @XAMlMAX yes, the behaviour is exactly the same for a Rectangle and for an InlineUIContainer with BaselineAlignment.Baseline

Comment: It has been a long time but I have found something interesting, when I use this `<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5">
            <TextBlock FontSize="100" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
        Hel<Border Width="20" Height="75" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5"/>lo!
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>` then shrink width the text until a dot appears under Border, then shrink Height and watch it retain it's size!